# How to increase the cpu utilisation of a process in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, process, cpu-usage, high-cpu-usage

I am doing a project for my college using WEKA, I am classifying a very large text file(300MB). But it is a very slow process.

I looked in the task manager and I saw that weka uses only 10% of the cpu, and overall cpu utilization is around 13%. I want to increase weka's cpu utilsation. I already set the priority of weka as 'high'.

My laptop has intel i3 processor(2.1GHz) with 6GB RAM.

Any ideas how can I do that? 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CPU is mostly idle and you appear to have plenty of RAM. It is likely that your process is slow because it is I/O bound. Is it reading data from a remote network drive or perhaps a website?

Comment: Actually, I suspect the process is related to disk usage - which is at 25%.   Do you know if the RAM figure includes swap ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that includes swap, but I doubt it. Your app is using a reasonable 1GB out of 6GB. Do you happen to be analyzing a large file? Perhaps the code is seeking back and forth across the file instead of reading it sequentially?